# setCountry doesnt update the country value

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to set a country as a default option in checkbox options,
I have three options: `United States`, `United Kingdom` and `Rest of the world`;
This is the Available countries constant which includes the iso codes of the mentioned countries:

```
const AVAILABLE_COUNTRIES: PartialDeep<Country[]> = [
  {
    isoCode: 'GB' as CountryCode,
    name: 'United Kingdom',
    currency: {
      isoCode: 'GBP' as CurrencyCode,
    },
  },
  {
    isoCode: 'US' as CountryCode,
    name: 'United States',
    currency: {
      isoCode: 'USD' as CurrencyCode,
    },
  },
];
```

The problem I am facing is when the page is rendered, there's no value checked as default.
how I can address this issue?

```
 const [country, setCountry] = useState('');
  const getCountryFromCode = useCallback((code: CountryCode) => {
    const selected = AVAILABLE_COUNTRIES.find(
      (country) => country?.isoCode === code.toUpperCase(),
    );
    return selected ? selected.isoCode?.toLowerCase() : 'row';
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchUserCountry = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await fetch('https://ipinfo.io?token=d0f95sdfdsfdsfxxx');
        const data = await response.json();

        if (data.country) {
          const userCountry = data.country;
          const matchingCountry = getCountryFromCode(userCountry);
          if (matchingCountry) {
            setCountry(matchingCountry);
            console.log(matchingCountry); // this displays us
          }
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error occurred while fetching user country:', error);
      }
    };

    fetchUserCountry();
  }, [getCountryFromCode]);
  const {
    formState: {errors, isDirty, isSubmitting, isSubmitSuccessful},
    handleSubmit,
    register,
    setError,
  } = useForm<
    FormValues & {
      serverError?: string;
    }
  >({
    defaultValues: {
      name: '',
      email: '',
      number: '',
      type: 'trade',
      country, // Country
      message: '',
    },
    resolver: yupResolver(schema),
  });
...
 <FormFieldSelect
          disabled={isSubmitting}
          error={errors.country?.message}
          label="Country/Region*"
          defaultValue={country}
          options={[
            {label: 'United Kingdom', value: 'gb'},
            {label: 'United States', value: 'us'},
            {label: 'Rest of the World', value: 'row'},
          ]}
          {...register('country')}
        />
```

this is the FormFieldSelect:

```
 <select
          aria-label={label}
          autoComplete={autoComplete}
          className={clsx([
            'w-full appearance-none rounded-xs border px-6 py-4 text-md leading-field',
            'bg-[url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB3aWR0aD0iOSIgaGVpZ2h0PSIxNSIgdmlld0JveD0iMCAwIDkgMTUiIGZpbGw9Im5vbmUiIHhtbG5zPSJodHRwOi8vd3d3LnczLm9yZy8yMDAwL3N2ZyI+CjxwYXRoIGQ9Ik04LjUgMTAuNUw0Ljc1IDE0LjI1TDEgMTAuNSIgc3Ryb2tlPSIjM0EzRTNFIiBzdHJva2UtbGluZWNhcD0icm91bmQiIHN0cm9rZS1saW5lam9pbj0icm91bmQiLz4KPHBhdGggZD0iTTEgNC43NUw0Ljc1IDFMOC41IDQuNzUiIHN0cm9rZT0iIzNBM0UzRSIgc3Ryb2tlLWxpbmVjYXA9InJvdW5kIiBzdHJva2UtbGluZWpvaW49InJvdW5kIi8+Cjwvc3ZnPgo=)] bg-[right_0.75rem_center] bg-no-repeat',
            'disabled:bg-gray/50 disabled:opacity-50',
            'focus:outline-1',
            error ? 'border-red' : 'border-darkGray/50',
          ])}
          defaultValue={defaultValue}
          disabled={disabled}
          id={name}
          name={name}
          onBlur={onBlur}
          onChange={onChange}
          placeholder={placeholder}
          ref={ref}
        >
          <option className="text-dark/50" disabled value="">
            {label}
          </option>
          {options?.map((option) => (
            <option key={option.value} value={option.value}>
              {option.label}
            </option>
          ))}
        </select>
```

Please note when I change to `const [country, setCountry] = useState('us');` eventually it does display the United state as a default option.

Comment: What is "FormFieldSelect"? To give a select option a value you do something like this ```<select value={my_value}></select>```.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<FormFieldSelect
              disabled={isSubmitting}
              error={errors.country?.message}
              label="Country/Region*"
              options={[
                {label: 'United Kingdom', value: 'gb'},
                {label: 'United States', value: 'us'},
                {label: 'Rest of the World', value: 'row'},
              ]}
              {...register('country')}
             defaultValue={options[1]}
            />
```

Comment: The default value must match the user's country, that's why I am using fetchUserCountry  to fetch the country

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).